# JQuery replace text with <br /> in nested table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have a little bit of Jquery which replaces all instances of **newline** on my XSL rendered webpage with `<br />` tags:

```
$("#ResultsPane td").each(function() {
  var text = ""
  text = $(this).text().replace(/newline/g, "<br />");
});
```

I have had to update the output to use nested tables:-

```
<td colspan="4">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding: 8px;width:70px;vertical-align:top;">08:10 - 12:30 newline 
          13:30 - 17:10 newline </td>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding: 8px;vertical-align:top;">
          20 newline 
          20 newline </td>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding: 8px;vertical-align:top;">
          Artesian Building newline 
          Artesian Building newline </td>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding: 8px;border-right:2px solid #000;vertical-align:top;"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

The net result however is that when the Jquery script runs, all of the nested tables are being converted to text only nodes.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you doesn't save changes. Also
you can use [`.html( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) instead of `.each()`

```js
$("#ResultsPane td").html(function(i, h){
  return h.replace(/newline/g, "<br />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ResultsPane">
  <tr><td colspan="4">
    <table>
      <tbody><tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding: 8px;width:70px;vertical-align:top;">08:10 - 12:30 newline 
          13:30 - 17:10 newline </td>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding: 8px;vertical-align:top;">
          20 newline 
          20 newline </td>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding: 8px;vertical-align:top;">
          Artesian Building newline 
          Artesian Building newline </td>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding: 8px;border-right:2px solid #000;vertical-align:top;"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My Jquery is very limited - the original snippet was provided to my by a colleague who has now left. This works perfectly.